# Categorical Nested Lists into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have three levels of categorical data that I need to convert into a Pandas DataFrame with repeating labels on the upper categories.  I have lists for "main", "sub", and "tertiary" as follows:

```
main_labels = ['Certain infectious and parasitic diseases','Neoplasms']
main_icds = ['A00-B99','C00-D49']
sub_labels = ['Intestinal infectious diseases','Tuberculosis','Malignant neoplasms of lip, oral cavity and pharynx','Malignant neoplasms of digestive organs']
sub_icds = ['A00-A09','A15-A19','C00-C14','C15-C26']
ter_labels = ['Cholera','Typhoid and paratyphoid fevers','Respiratory tuberculosis','Tuberculosis of nervous system','Malignant neoplasm of lip','Malignant neoplasm of base of tongue','Malignant neoplasm of esophagus','Malignant neoplasm of stomach']
ter_icds = ['A00','A01','A15','A17','C00','C01','C15','C16']
```

For illustration and example purposes, I need them to look like below in a Pandas DataFrame. If I can accomplish this, I can add in the label values.

[image]

It seemed like it would be easy but I'm stumped. Any help greatly appreciated. I tried searching historical posts but was having trouble finding the right key words to get anything close to what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to start with the ternary category, then find its sub and main classifications.  python allows inequalities on alphanumeric strings, so this should be pretty robust.

```
import pandas as pd

main_icds = ['A00-B99','C00-D49']
sub_icds = ['A00-A09','A15-A19','C00-C14','C15-C26']
ter_icds = ['A00','A01','A15','A17','C00','C01','C15','C16']

#split on '-' to get bounds for each category
subs = [sub.split('-') for sub in sub_icds]
mains = [main.split('-') for main in main_icds]

df = pd.DataFrame({'ter_icd':ter_icds})
df['sub_icd'] = [sub_icd for ter in ter_icds 
                     for sub_icd,sub in zip(sub_icds,subs) 
                         if (ter >= sub[0]) & (ter <= sub[1])]
df['main_icd'] = [main_icd for ter in ter_icds 
                      for main_icd,main in zip(main_icds,mains)
                          if (ter >= main[0]) & (ter <= main[1])]
```

Comment: VERY NICE!!  Thank you!!